# Deploy Django Channels with Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, redis, django-channels

I'm trying to deploy django channels with Docker and Django doesn't seem to find Redis (which I'm using as a channel layer).

When I do it locally, I just run `redis-server` and point to it from settings:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('localhost', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

Everything works fine, web sockets are accepting connections and easily transfer my data. For production environment I use this docker config:

```
version: "3"

services:

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    restart: 'on-failure'
    image: registry.testtesttest.com/app/backend:${BACKEND_VERSION:-latest}
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: ${DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE:-settings.production}
      DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: ${DJANGO_SECRET_KEY:-dev}

    redis:
        image: "redis:alpine"
        ports: 
           -"6379:6379"
```

And I point to redis from production settings:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('redis', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

And on production, Django says:

> Cannot find redis on 127.0.0.1:6379

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to add any extra services do docker-compose file?

Comment: Change `'localhost'` to the redis container name.

Comment: @KlausD. it's 'redis', localhost I'm using only for dev environment. There's a production config in my answer.

Comment: The container name usually contains an underscore in docker-compose.

Comment: @KlausD. how is it should be displayed for my docker setup?

Comment: `docker ps` or see the name in the output of `docker-compose up`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give links for backend.

```
backend:
    container_name: backend
    restart: 'on-failure'
    image: registry.testtesttest.com/app/backend:${BACKEND_VERSION:-latest}
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: ${DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE:-settings.production}
      DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: ${DJANGO_SECRET_KEY:-dev}
    links:
     - redis
```